# OS X: Apply inheritable ACL permissions to pre-existing subfolders and files

Tags: permissions, osx, acl

I have a folder with numerous ACL permissions set. Most of these include `file_inherit` and `directory_inherit` permissions and therefore should be, and are, automatically propagated to any new sub-folders and files I create within that folder.

However, there are some sub-folders and files that were already in the folder with the ACL permissions before the ACL permissions were set. Because of this, they don't have the inheritable permissions.

How can I make all the pre-existing sub-folders and files inherit the inheritable ACL permissions, as if they were newly created?